# How to plot a graph if only event points are given?

Tags: java, excel, graph, d3.js, diagram

I am trying to plot availability of node (machine). In order to save storage on data collected, instead of recording data on fixed interval, I record them based on events (ADDED, REMOVED). ADDED means "up", REMOVED means "down/unreachable"

Here's the sample data I have:

```
2012-11-25 11:11:11.1234 - node added.
2012-11-25 15:01:20.1234 - node removed.
2012-11-25 18:12:12.1234 - node added.
```

Let's say, I want to plot a graph from time range: 2012-11-24 to 2012-11-25 (x-axis), Up/Down (y-axis) , how do I plot the graph?

Comment: One easy way would be to calculate a time series of the cumulative sum of the "node added" (+1) and "node removed" (-1) events.  Then you can produce a scatterplot of date/time versus the cumulative sum.  Depending on the data, this might be good enough.

Comment: There is two challenges: 1. should I plot the data before 2012-11-25 11:11:11 as node removed? 2. The unit of time that event occur may not be the discrete graph unit, e.g. interval of x-axis is 5 minute-unit.

Answer (score 0):

i think there are some examples (i cant remember which one) in the d3 tools (http://d3js.org)

If you look through the examples you can choose the type of visualisation you want to use.
I think the data set you have would match to what you are trying to do (you may need to write a small operator to convert to the up/down comment to an integer).

Answer (score 0):

If you have all your data stored in an array, simply use JavaScript's built in [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method, and use JavaScript's [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object to convert the timestamp into milliseconds (note that it'll round to the nearest thousandth of a second - only 3 decimal places).

```
var startTime = Date.parse("2012-11-24"),
    endTime = Date.parse("2012-11-25") + 86400000; /* Add one day */

filteredData = data.filter(function(d) {
    var time = Date.parse(d.time);
    return (time >= startTime && time < endTime);
});
```

You'll may need to play around with the date ranges, I'm assuming you mean that you want data which is on between 2012-11-24 and 2012-11-25 inclusive.

---

If your data is in a database, another way would be just to simply query the database to only display data which exists within the time range (you could call some PHP script - using [`d3.text`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_text) - which outputs JSON and accepts two GET parameters, startTime and endTime).

```
d3.text("getNodes.php?startTime=" + startTime + "&endTime=" + endTime, function(json) {
    filteredData = JSON.parse(json);
});
```